# Why does my dock's "Automatically Hide" keep getting re-enabled?

Tags: dock, settings

I repeatedly see that the Dock is in auto-hide mode. So, I go to settings and disable auto-hide. Yet soon enough, auto-hide returns.

How can I keep this setting from re-enabling itself?

[image]

(macOS Monterey 12.3.1)

Comment: If you have (even inadvertently) used the keyboard shortcut option+command+D it turns on (or off) this setting.

Comment: Full screen mode also hides the dock.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131854/turn-off-auto-hiding-dock-and-menu-bar?rq=1 (If you can add a little more context to your question, such as when do you notice the change? Moving between apps or spaces? etc)  Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk Good idea? I doubt that I have used it repeatedly, but if this problem recurs I can use that to disable the hiding

Comment: @bjbk If Full Screen Mode were the cause, the configuration setting wouldn't keep reverting to "enabled". I notice that it is re-enabled occasionally, every few hours during the working day

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that after posting the comment, but left it there anyway.  Hope you get to the source of the issue.  Cheers

Comment: BLESS you @bjbk, finally I have my dock back! At least on my Monterey machine option+command+D does not check or uncheck the boxes in the Preferences menu, making this problem super hard to figure out

Comment: see: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5026935 — `defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide -bool FALSE; killall Dock`

Answer (score 17):

@bjbk's comment to use <kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> fixed it for me.

> If you have (even inadvertently) used the keyboard shortcut option+command+D it turns on (or off) this setting.

### Disable keyboard shortcut

You can disable the keyboard shortcut by opening *System Settings* and searching for "Keyboard shortcuts". Uncheck "Turn Dock hiding on/off".

[image: Keyboard shortcut setting]

Comment: I think that's how it was getting flipped for me--I have that custom-shortcut in my Windows VM Visual Studio and the mac picks it up. And I just tested window vs. coherence (Parallels) and the mac picks it up keystroke even when parallels VM has focus.  Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the tiny dividing line in the dock, and you will see <kbd>**Turn Hiding On/Off**</kbd> as seen below:

[image: macos dock autohide]

From the same dock context menu you can access the corresponding MacOS Settings page via <kbd>**Dock Settings...**</kbd>

And now the important part: if you have a dual monitor setup ️ ️, AND you disabled the option <kbd>Displays have separate Spaces</kbd> then you will have the scenario described in the original question where dock hiding seems to turn itself on out of the blue.
When using multiple displays you *must* make sure that **Displays have separate Spaces** is set to ON (on Ventura the option is the last one in the Dock Settings prefs pane which can be opened from the context menu).

[image: displays have separate spaces must be ON for dual monitor setups]

To get the dock context menu hover above the tiny line in the dock until the cursor turns into resize mode **↔️**, and then right-click (this area is also used to click+drag to adjust the size of the dock):

[image: dock resize area]